# How to check whether QTP is launched in remote machine using VBS

Tags: c#, vbscript, webserver, qtp

I am trying to launch QTP on a remote server using VBS. I am running VBS file using C# code. When I am running my C# application from local machine it's giving me VBS error messages if there is any error in VBS file. But when I am running the same C# application after deploying to our server it's not giving me any error messages even if there is an error in my VBS file. Can some one please help me with this?

**C# Code**

```
protected void btnExecuteScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\test1.vbs");
}
```

**VBS Code**

```vbs
Dim qtApp 
Dim qtTest 
Dim qtResultsOpt 

Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application","Server Name")

If Window("HP Unified Functional Testing") _
    .Dialog("HP Unified Functional Testing").Exist(60) = False Then

  MsgBox("Hello world")

End If

qtApp.Launch 
qtApp.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to see if QTP is running is to use the automation model directly. The `qtApp` object supports the boolean `Launched` property which:

> Indicates whether QuickTest is currently open.

Comment: Hi Motti, Can you please let me know whether we can initiate QTP in a remote machine using C# code. I know we can do it through VBS. Below is the code i used in C# for invoking QTP in my local machine. Can you please tell me where to add the remote machine IP address in this C# code.                                                           QuickTest.Application QTPInstance = new QuickTest.Application();
QTPInstance.Launch();
QTPInstance.Visible = true;

Comment: @user545359, I didn't notice the `"Server Name"` part of your question, in any case the `Launched` property is available in VBS too (it's the same interface exposed to different environments).